# How to enable and disable toast with toggle button in Android?

Tags: android, toast, android-togglebutton

I have toggle button which work good for some function. But when I use for toast, toggle button is null pointer.

This is my code:

```
if (tgbutton.isChecked()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MY TEXT HERE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

App is working well when use toast with no toggle button, but app is crashed when I used toast with toggle button.

**How to use toast with toggle button?**

Thanks

**EDIT:**

This is from logcat:

> 05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mygames.testpackage2/com.testpackage.challenge.CH__QuestionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.ToggleButton.isChecked()' on a null object reference
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.ToggleButton.isChecked()' on a null object reference
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at com.testpackage.challenge.CH__QuestionActivity.displayQuestion(CH__QuestionActivity.java:613)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at com.testpackage.challenge.CH__QuestionActivity.displayNextQuestion(CH__QuestionActivity.java:554)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at com.testpackage.challenge.CH__QuestionActivity.onCreate(CH__QuestionActivity.java:218)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
>   05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777):    ... 10 more

Comment: post the stack trace of the exception that caused the crash

Comment: I add logcat. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace show that your tgbutton is `null`.

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.ToggleButton.isChecked()' on a null object reference 05-20 21:59:07.568: E/AndroidRuntime(26777)`

There are 2 things you should to correct:

**1) Make sure to bind your view.**

```
ToggleButton tgButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.your_tg_button_id);
```

**2) Make sure to check `null` before use:**

```
if (null != tgbutton && tgbutton.isChecked()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MY TEXT HERE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is about Context that you pass to toast.

```
if (tgbutton.isChecked()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "MY TEXT HERE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

or if you are in fragment,

```
if (tgbutton.isChecked()) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "MY TEXT HERE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Make sure you call this from UI thread.

Good luck there

Emre

Comment: I will check. Thanks @emre-aktürk

Comment: If not, can you also provide crash log please?

Comment: 05-20 21:53:59.025: E/AndroidRuntime(26122): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.ToggleButton.isChecked()' on a null object reference

Comment: Your both suggestion is not working.Do you have any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`tgButton` is not initialized. Ensure it is initialized by:

```
ToggleButton tgButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.your_tg_button_id);
```

Comment: Toggle button is work fine with another function, eg. sound on/off.

I was initialized like this:

tgbutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);

Answer (score 0):

Solution:-

```
ToggleButton tb;

tb = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggle_button_id);

if(tb.equals("ON") {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Else Part", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Cheers!!

P.S : I think, it is not a good practice to use `isChecked()` for ToggleButton.

From the report of logcat you may found that ToggleButton is having only boolean

of options (On or Off). So you need not to verify with `isChecked()` function.